# Calling information from request inside a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django app using authentication where user's can view one another's profiles.

In my views.py

```
def display(request, edit=False, pk=None): 
    if not pk:
        pk = request.user.profile.pk

    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    d = get_user_info(profile) # returns a dictionary of some info from a user's profile

    if edit and request.user == profile.user:
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', d)
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', d)
```

Inside my template I would like to give a user the option to click a link allowing them to edit information if they are viewing their own profile.

```
{% if request.user == profile.user %}
    <a href="{% url "edit_profile" %}">edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

I have two questions about this.
First: I thought using render() allowed me to access `request` inside the template. However, that's not working. Am I doing it wrong? Or do I need to explicitly pass `render` with the dictionary?

```
d['request']=request    
return render(request, 'profile.html', d)
```

Second: Is this okay to do? Or should I be doing this some other way?

Comment: yes you can use dictionary or the context processor request too but with this last you need to add more settings in settings.py

Comment: show a piece of the model , it will be more helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) that adds `request` object in template context.
This is not added by default so you need to enable that in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings.

However, django adds current `request.user` as `user` context variable, so you can use that if that is sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen this in a few other posts, but there isn't a `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `system.py. Do I just add it in?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446558/where-is-template-context-processor-in-django-1-5/15446953#15446953