# How to get the request.path in django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need the request.path in my template tag. But the problem is, my django version is 1.5.1 and I dont have the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, so there's no `django.core.context_processors.request`. Now, its giving me the error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'str' object has no attribute 'path'
Exception Location:C:\Users\Nanyoo\web\pics\album\templatetags\active_tags.py in active, line 8
```

Is there any other way to get the desired path in the template?

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html", {'photos':photos})
```

active_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def active(request, pattern):
    import re
    if re.search(pattern, request.path):
        return 'active'
    return ''
```

Comment: Please pass the request object in the dict `{'photos':photos, 'request':request}`and try.

Comment: Perfect! Please post your comment as the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pass the request object in the Context dictionary.

```
def home(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html", {'photos':photos,'request':request})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the request object to be always available in your templates, you can add to the default template context processors.  See the answer here:

[Where is template context processor in Django 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446558/where-is-template-context-processor-in-django-1-5)

Basically, put this in your settings.py:

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```